# get values out from elements webdriver with Nightwatch/Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, nightwatch.js

I am trying to get out the text from a `HTML` element and then store these values in an array so I can later compare values in my tests.

```
<div class=".react-grid-HeaderCell-sortable">Jamie</div>
<div class=".react-grid-HeaderCell-sortable">Hutber</div>
<div class=".react-grid-HeaderCell-sortable">Stackoverflow</div>
```

In the end, I would like an array that equals:

```
['jamie', 'hutber', 'stackoverflow']
```

**My Code**

```
module.exports = {
  tags: ['someTest'],
  'Test login': function (browser) {
       browser
      .elements('css selector', '.react-grid-Header .react-grid-HeaderCell-sortable', (items) => {
        items.value.forEach(item => {
          item //{...}
          item.ELEMENT //123123123.12 (an id of some sort)?
          console.info(driver.findElement(By.id(item.ELEMENT))); //driver is undefined
        });
      })
    }
}
```

Comment: define values. From your post it's not clear whether you want the rendered text, a DOM attribute or a DOM property.

Comment: Sorry you're right. I will update the question

Comment: The value `item.ELEMENT` is a marshaling reference. Use `browser.elementIdText(item.ELEMENT, txt => console.info(txt))` to get the text. Though a better approach would be to get the text from the parent container: `client.expect.element('.react-grid').text.to.equal('jamie hutber stackoverflow');`

Comment: I don't know a lot about nightwatch, but isn't `browser` your web driver in this case? You would probably want to change `driver.findElement...` to `browser.findElement...`